# Bind array of objects to $scope

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, mean-stack

```
<div data-ng-repeat="div in divs">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="user.fname[$index]">
    <label>Second Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="sname" ng-model="user.sname[$index]">
</div>
<button ng-click="addDivs()">Add More Person</button>


angular.module('user', []).controller('UserCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.divs = [1];
    $scope.addDivs = function(){
        $scope.divs.push({});
    }
}
```

When we have 2 divs
required format of data is :

> [ {   fname:'name1',  sname:'name2' }, {  fname:'name3', 
>   sname:'name4' } ]

But the output came as:

> { fname:[ 'name1', 'name3' ], sname:[ 'name2', 'name ]}

How to model the html to get the data in desired format?

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me, although this may not solve your problem, is that in your template you reference 'sname' but in the code format you say you require you have 'scname' (notice the spelling discrepancy).

Comment: `$scope.user=[];` and `<input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="user[$index].fname">` same for `sname` - `ng-model="user[$index].sname"` - https://plnkr.co/edit/sqEZexWeiR6WwfiSf0BL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are expecting ?

```js
angular.module('user', []).controller('UserCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.persons = [];  
  $scope.addDivs = function(){
        $scope.persons.push({fname: $scope.user.fname, sname: $scope.user.sname});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="user" ng-controller="UserCtrl">
<div>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="user.fname">
    <label>Second Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="sname" ng-model="user.sname">
</div>
  <div data-ng-repeat="person in persons"> {{person.fname}}  {{person.sname}}</div>
<button ng-click="addDivs()">Add More Person</button>

</div>
```